# how can I do transition animation separately?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm practicing setting `transition`and `transform` CSS property dynamically using vanilla Javascript. It is conceptually difficult to understand...

There are three test cases in code snippet. **Could you explain the reason for these results?**

- case 1: `transition` property is not work. the position of the box is set from the first, no animation.
- case 2(Asynchronous): Why does this work well?
- case 3(move twice): Why it doesn't go to 0% position?

And `case 4` is what I want to do. No matter where the box was, I want to move to zero position immediately, turn on the transition, and move to specific position with animation. **How can I implement this?**

```js
function setPosition(item, position) {
  item.style.transform = `translate(${position}%)`;
}

function setOnTransition(item) {
  item.style.transition = 'transform 1.5s ease 0s';
  item.style.webkitTransition = 'transform 1.5s ease 0s';
}

function setOffTransition(item) {
  item.style.transition = '';
  item.style.webkitTransition = '';
}

let box = document.querySelector('div');

/* case 1

setOnTransition(box);
setPosition(box, 200);
*/

/* case 2 

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setOnTransition(box);
    setPosition(box, 200);
});
*/

/* case 3

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setOnTransition(box);
    setPosition(box, 0);
    setPosition(box, 200);
});
*/

/* case 4

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    setPosition(box, 0);
    setOnTransition(box);
    setPosition(box, 200);
});
*/
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate(100%);
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially all down to browser optimization. If you perform several quick modifications to an element's attributes with JS, then the browser will automatically choose the end state and skip all the intervening ones. This is to avoid display flashing and improve user experience, although it can get in the way in situations like this.

In your first case, the page loads and immediately runs the script, so the browser optimises to the new end position.

In your second case, the transition is added and executed after page load with an event, meaning no optimization takes place.

In your third and fourth cases, the browser skips over the call to reset as it is immediately reversed by the call back to the adjusted position.

The solution is [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), which will allow you to bypass the optimisation process and intricately control changes to an element's attributes. It is most often used for updating `style` and `classList`.

```js
function setPosition(item, position) {
  item.style.transform = `translate(${position}%)`;
}

function setOnTransition(item) {
  item.style.transition = 'transform 1.5s ease 0s';
  item.style.webkitTransition = 'transform 1.5s ease 0s';
}

function setOffTransition(item) {
  item.style.transition = '';
  item.style.webkitTransition = '';
}

let box = document.querySelector('div');

function resetAndRepaint() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    setOffTransition(box);
    setPosition(box, 100);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      setOnTransition(box);
      setPosition(box, 200);
    })
  });
};

box.addEventListener('click', resetAndRepaint);
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: translate(100%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```